# Dates calculation with Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I  have a table with a `date` as datetime and a month count as `int`.

How can I get all entities with EF that are

`date + month_count > today's date - 7 days`

table structure

```
id uniqueidentifier
date datetime
month_count int
```

Answer (score 0):

For performance reasons you might want to consider executing the date calculations directly in SQL:

```
using (var dbContext = new DbContext())
{
    var result = from entity in dbContext.Entities.SqlQuery(
        @"SELECT * FROM entities 
          WHERE 
              DATEDIFF(d, 
                  DATEADD(m, [month_count], [date]), 
                  GETDATE()) > -7");
}
```

Read more about using SQL with EntityFramework [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907(v=vs.113).aspx)

An alternative is to just load the lot into memory, and sort it using non SQL aware LINQ:

```
using (var dbContext = new DbContext())
{
    var oneWeekAgo = (DateTime.Now() - TimeSpan.FromDays(7)).Date();
    var result = from entity in dbContext.Entities.ToList()
        where entity.Date + TimeSpan.FromMonths(entity.MonthCount) 
            > oneWeekAgo;
}
```